# Phonegap Application text and layout too small

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I recently build an android app using html, css, javascript and running them through phonegap to create the actual app. One of the problems I encountered in one phone is that the text looks too small. Also some images are a little small as well. I added a viewport meta tag but it doesnt seem to work either. Here are the meta tags:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`
```

This is how it looks
[image: This happens in a particular phone(Samsung Galaxy)]

This is how its supposed to look:
[image: This is how it looks in htc wildfire s]

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it changing the viewport.
I also thought the problem was phonegap, but it really was that the devices used for testing had different dpi.

My solution was to change the target-densitydpi on the viewport to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: This is the way to do it. Won't cause any issues on blackberry either.

Comment: very helpful, and surprising that `medium-dpi` works better than `device-dpi`

Comment: I had this problem in my android and BB build. Thanks you

Comment: You my friend are a life saver. Hugs, Kisses, et al... Last minute fix before a client meeting. +100

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html This page may also shed some light on what Android phones are doing for medium,low and high density,

Comment: Note that setting it to medium-dpi looses fidelity, if you want to track touchmove precisely.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and did some research I thought is worth sharing:

- Set the viewport's `target-densitydpi` to `medium-dpi` (=160dpi), as already suggested. This virtualizes the `px` unit, e.g. `1px` in html/css then corresponds to 2 physical pixels on a 320dpi device. Note that images are scaled (and blurred) as well.

  ```
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
  ```
- CSS: Use media queries to implement conditional styling. Adapting for different screen sizes dependent on width, height, aspect or orientation is straight-forward. Different pixel densities can be handled with `device-pixel-ratio` (thanks to Marc Edwards for providing an example: https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599).

  ```
  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
         screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 15/10)
  {
    body { background-image: ... } /* provide high-res image */
  }
  ```

  The media feature `resolution` is cleaner than `device-pixel-ratio`, but it lacks mobile browser support.
- Javascript: Adapt button sizes, images etc. based on `window.devicePixelRatio` and `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`. Layouting per Javascript is considered as bad practice. Also flickering might result during loading as the execution starts after the `pageload` event.
- `-webkit-image-set` and image `src-set` make it easy to provide high-res images for retina displays, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/#toc-bff. Browser support is limited.

  ```
   background-image: -webkit-image-set(
     url(icon1x.jpg) 1x,
     url(icon2x.jpg) 2x
   );
  ```

Answer (score 5):

It appears that removing the `target-densitydpi` altogether brings the best results.

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />`

This should be more than enough to control your app's appearance in most cases.

Comment: This should have marked as the correct answer! I was facing blur issues on few devices when the viewport had the attributes mentioned in the answer marked as correct.

Answer (score 4):

target-densitydpi=medium-dpi Worked for us.

Scenario
Faced this issue when ee upgraded from PhoneGap 2.2 to 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:** for **Android**

The problem is on Android devices has this **Accessibilly** settings, You can try to change font-size *(search **font size** on android setting*) and run you app again.

**So your fonts on app will be changed as your setting**

[image: Accessibilly font size]

---

### So here is a solution for Cordova

**Use :** [mobile-accessibility](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility) to disabling **PreferredTextZoom**

Install **mobile-accessibility** on your Cordova project

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility.git
```

And **JS part** is something like :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   if (window.MobileAccessibility) {
      window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone (WP8) I've found the following solution:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/92

1. add to css: @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }
2. add to html: 
   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`
3. add to  to patch IE 10:

   (function() {
   if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/10.0/)) {
       var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
       msViewportStyle.appendChild(
           document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
       );
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
   }
   })();

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tested it to see if it works, but good to know

Answer (score -2):

Adding this solution here

For me, some text were rendering really big, others were the correct size.
The problem was with the use of rem values for font-size in the css. For some reason, elements where the font-size was the base value (defined in the body) were rendered way bigger than they should.

The fix was to reassign a global value for the rem font-size in a wrapper element for the entire site.

(my .font-size(1.4) is only a mixin rendering: font-size: 1.4rem; )

So this

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  .font-size(1.4);
}

h1 {
  .font-size(2.6);
}
```

Can be fixed with this

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  .font-size(1.4);
}

.wrapper {
  .font-size(1.4);
}

h1 {
  .font-size(2.6);
}
```