# Phonegap : how Control the font size of the Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

In Phonegap I have come across the problem, that if we change the font size of the mobile device from the setting to normal to large then the css which has applied to the application breaks.

So how to overcome this problem ? I have searched a lot but not able to find any solution regarding it.

Any help or advice would be helpful.

It works fine when device font-size is normal.
[Image here](http://i59.tinypic.com/2vdqudy.png)

As I change the device font-size from setting>Display>fonts to Huge
[Image here](http://i62.tinypic.com/15716b4.png)

Comment: I don't know answer of this problem but if you don't have to use the system font, it seems to be helpful to use a custom font. Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454681/custom-fonts-in-android-phonegap)

Comment: You're trying to change the font size in css and the application breaks?  Could you provide some code so we know what you're trying to do?  It's possible there's another error cuasing it to crash that you're just not seeing.  Also, any info from VS or whatever tool you're using would be helpful.

Comment: thank for your reply guys,I am making no change in css..
css works fine when device fonts are normal but when i change the font from setting>display>font to huge the css breaks..I have updated the question and added the screenshots links.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just found out the solution exactly as i need.
By using [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility).

And Just write the following in your onDeviceReady function in index.js.

```
 if(window.MobileAccessibility){
        window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);
    }
```

This will just ignore the system font preferences.

Comment: Nice @AJ-- Your Solution Works for me. Great

Comment: I amd glad that the solution worked for you guys @BhumeshPurohit

Comment: @MashukKhan happy to help. :)

Comment: I have some problem installing the plugin in phonegap. If anyone else have proble in installation via git, can try to install normally using this sequence:
- phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
- phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility

Answer (score 1):

By the information you passed I think that if you adjust the media queries, and the viewport you will have the desired result.

Viewport example. [Phonegap Application text and layout too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194940/phonegap-application-text-and-layout-too-small)

Media queries example. [Scaling a Phonegap app for different Android screen sizes/densities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456183/scaling-a-phonegap-app-for-different-android-screen-sizes-densities)

Comment: thx for the answer Nikolaos,But  viewport not a issue thought tried answer given in your link(not working) and regarding the scaling a phonegap app yes my app scaling on different screen size no prob in that.Issue only occur when device font size is changed to huge.
I just want to ignore the system font size. :) :)