# Meteor cordova layout not correct

Tags: css, cordova, meteor

my meteor app was able to run in browser just fine even i access my webapp from my phone is ok but when i try to build it as apk the layout all gone wrong. i suspect it have wrong line height but after all the debugging i still can't found out why. is there any specific CSS or font rule in cordova meteor app i dont know?
from phone app

[image]

and from phone browser

[image]

i had checked all css rule are the same is just that the same line height  but in the phone app is display incorrectly.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: Sorry Was just asking if there any android Cordova specific  layout thing I must know because it is non code related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the system device font size that cause the problem found a fix by following [Phonegap : how Control the font size of the Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848132/phonegap-how-control-the-font-size-of-the-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

try using the below meta tag, put it in your head file.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: thank already got the answer, already put that in the meta tag is more of font problem