# How do I make Font Size on PhoneGap match Desktop and Web?

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, phonegap

I'm new to PhoneGap and noticed a problem... When testing my app on a desktop computer, or even if I put the app online and view it in a webpage (I'm on android and tried chrome browser and Samsung browser). It appears the same.  However, if I view it with the phonegap app on my phone, the font size if different. Here's a simple example...

```css
body {font:normal 26px arial}
div{width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<div>THIS IS A TEST</div>
```

Notice, the words THIS IS A TEST fit nicely across the div.  With phonegap, it doesn't fit.  It's enlarging the font. I did some testing and it's not changing the div size, it's definitely a Font issue.  I was hoping to have things look the same on desktop and mobile, without having to alter font sizes and detect devices.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible it has something to do with the font size set by the device itself?

You can take a look at this answer, it may be of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848132/phonegap-how-control-the-font-size-of-the-mobile

Comment: Make sure you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` on your pages.