# How to control font size exactly in PhoneGap / WebView, overriding possible settings?

Tags: cordova, webview, fonts, font-size, phonegap

I use PhoneGap/Cordova for developing a small app on a WebView. In order to control the **exact** design, I adjust in runtime (in JavaScript) the original sizes into new sizes, based on the actual screen width and height. Font sizes go through the same process. It generally works great, **except** for some cases where phone settings were used to change the default font size (see screenshot below).

Is there a way to **override** the system font size settings and still control **exactly** my font sizes? Here is a fragment of the code demonstrating the method. Note the font size manipulation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="all" class="all">
      <div id="main" class="main">
        <div id="ext" class="extCls">
          <div id="tabDiv1" class="tabDiv1Cls">
            <img id="tabImg1" class="tabImg" src="img/tabImgOnCls.png" draggable="false" />
            <div id="tabTxt1" class="tabTxt">&nbsp;&nbsp;Prove</div>
          </div>
          <div id="tabDiv2" class="tabDiv2Cls">
            <img id="tabImg2" class="tabImg" src="img/tabImgCls.png" draggable="false" />
            <div id="tabTxt2" class="tabTxt">&nbsp;&nbsp;Read</div>
          </div>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {margin:0; border:0; padding:0; background-color:#c9c9c9; font-family:Calibri,Arial; font-size:14px; color:#0070b8; overflow:auto;}
.all {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0; z-index:2;}
.main {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0; background-color:#c9c9c9; overflow:hidden; z-index:10;}
.extCls {display:block; position:absolute; top:3.409%; left:4.444%; width:90%; height:93.344%; margin:0; border:2px solid; border-radius:6px; padding:0; background-color:#f4f4f4; border-color:#bcbcbc; z-index:20;}
.tabDiv1Cls, .tabDiv2Cls {display:block; position:absolute; top:-1.913%; width:21.605%; height:7.304%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0; font-size:2.922%; overflow:hidden; cursor:pointer; z-index:30;}
.tabDiv1Cls {left:8.642%;}
.tabDiv2Cls {left:31.481%;}
.tabImg {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0; cursor:pointer; z-index:40;}
.tabTxt {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0; line-height:233%; color:#ffffff; text-align:center; cursor:pointer; z-index:50;}
...
```

```
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", start);
  }
}());
function start() {
  var MYWID = 360, MYHIG = 616;  // the original design
  var scrWid,scrHig,wid,hig,lef;
  scrWid = window.innerWidth; scrHig = window.innerHeight;
  if (scrWid/scrHig <= MYWID/MYHIG) { wid = scrWid; hig = Math.floor(MYHIG * scrWid / MYWID); lef = 0;}
  else { wid = Math.floor(MYWID * scrHig / MYHIG); hig = scrHig; lef = Math.floor((scrWid - wid) / 2);}
  document.getElementById("main").style.width = wid + "px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.height = hig + "px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.top = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.bottom = "auto";
  document.getElementById("main").style.left = lef + "px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.fontSize = hig + "px";
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override system accessibility settings using:[phonegap-mobile-accessibility](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility)

Add the plugin and then in onDeviceReady() add the following:

```
if (window.MobileAccessibility) {
    window.MobileAccessibility.usePreferredTextZoom(false);
}
```

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, and I also found it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848132/phonegap-how-control-the-font-size-of-the-mobile

Comment: It's 2023 and this does not work in Cordova.